# HTTP Get Request from NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create http get request from node, to get information from youtube URL. When I click it in browser I get json response but if I try it from node, I get ssl and other types of error. What I have done is,

```
this.getApiUrl(params.videoInfo, function (generatedUrl) {
// Here is generated URL - // https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyAm_1TROkfNgY-bBuHmSaletJhVQmkycJc&id=_H_r9qVrf24&part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cplayer%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus

    console.log(generatedUrl);
    var req = http.get(generatedUrl, function (response) {
        var str = '';
        console.log('Response is ' + response.statusCode);
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log(str);
        });
    });
    req.end();
    req.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

I get this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Protocol \"https:\" not supported. Expected \"http:\".",
    "error": {}
  }
}
```

When I make it without `https` I get this error,

Response is 403

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"sslRequired","message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}],"code":403,"message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}}
```

Comment: What about var https = require('https') ? then using https.get(....) to make the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) module as opposed to the http module from node, also I would suggest one of many http libraries that provide a higher level api such as wreck or restler which allow you to control the protocol via options as opposed to a different required module.

Comment: No worries @Sankalp hoped it helped!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is obviously accessing content served securely with http request hence, the error. As I have commented in your question, you can make use of https rather than http and that should work but, you can also use any of the following approaches.

Using **[request](https://github.com/request/request)** module as follow:

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyAm_1TROkfNgY-bBuHmSaletJhVQmkycJc&id=_H_r9qVrf24&part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cplayer%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus";

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body);
  }
});
```

Using **[https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html)** module you can do like below:

```
var https = require('https');

 var options = {
        hostname: 'www.googleapis.com', //your hostname youtu
        port: 443,
        path: '//youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyAm_1TROkfNgY-bBuHmSaletJhVQmkycJc&id=_H_r9qVrf24&part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cplayer%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus',
        method: 'GET'
 };

  //or https.get() can also be used if not specified in options object
  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
      process.stdout.write(d);
    });
  });
  req.end();

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

You can also use **[requestify](https://github.com/ranm8/requestify)** module and

```
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyAm_1TROkfNgY-bBuHmSaletJhVQmkycJc&id=_H_r9qVrf24&part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cplayer%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus";
      requestify.get(url).then(function(response) {
          // Get the response body
          console.log(response.body);
      });
```

**[superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)** module is another option

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyAm_1TROkfNgY-bBuHmSaletJhVQmkycJc&id=_H_r9qVrf24&part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cplayer%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus";
  superagent('GET', url).end(function(response){
    console.log('Response text:', response.body);
});
```

Last but not least is the [**unirest**](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html) module allow you to make http/https request as simple as follow:

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyAm_1TROkfNgY-bBuHmSaletJhVQmkycJc&id=_H_r9qVrf24&part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cplayer%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus";
  unirest.get(url).end(function(res) {
    console.log(res.raw_body);
  });
```

There might be more options out there. Obviously you need to load the modules using require before using it

```
var request = require('request');
var https = require('https');
var requestify = require('requestify');
var superagent = require('superagent');
var unirest = require('unirest');
```

I provided extra details, not only to answer the question but, also to help others who browse for similiar question on how to make http/https request in nodejs.